# How to prevent Spring Boot Devtools from caching few files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, spring-boot, spring-cache

I am using spring cache to cache my database results, when spring cache is enabled along with spring boot devtools we receive weird exception ClassCastException due to known [limitation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-known-restart-limitations) is spring dev tools.

Now I want to exclude the class which contains cache from auto restart or reload, How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this issue pretty easily.

First of, you can disable caching completely, simply add the following to your configuration:

```
spring.cache.type=none
```

You could add that as a system property, or in the run configuration of your IDE so that it only applies when you're using devtools on your box.

Then you can switch to a cache manager implementation that does not serialize the content of object. One way to achieve that is to create a cache manager in memory with a certain profile:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public DevConfig {

  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new SimpleCacheManager();
  }
}
```

And then enable the dev profile (again via a property or in the run config of your IDE). This might now work if you have complex eviction rules.

Finally, you can fix the underlying problem by adding (including) the cache library (the component that is responsible of the serialization) in the application classloader. See [this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The restart technology provided by Spring Boot works by using two classloaders. Classes that do not change (for example, those from third-party jars) are loaded into a base classloader. Classes that you are actively developing are loaded into a restart classloader. When the application is restarted, the restart classloader is thrown away and a new one is created. This approach means that application restarts are typically much faster than “cold starts”, since the base classloader is already available and populated.

By default, any open project in your IDE is loaded with the “restart” classloader, and any regular .jar file is loaded with the “base” classloader. If you work on a multi-module project, and not every module is imported into your IDE, you may need to customize things. To do so, you can create a **META-INF/spring-devtools.properties** file.

The spring-devtools.properties file can contain properties prefixed with restart.exclude and restart.include. The include elements are items that should be pulled up into the “restart” classloader, and the exclude elements are items that should be pushed down into the “base” classloader. The value of the property is a regex pattern that is applied to the classpath, as shown in the following example:

```
restart.exclude.companycommonlibs=/mycorp-common-[\\w\\d-\.]+\.jar
restart.include.projectcommon=/mycorp-myproj-[\\w\\d-\.]+\.jar
```

see [Spring boot devtools docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload)